# MySQL Multiple foreign keys pointing to same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table called teams  and a table called games.   teams has id, name, .....    the games has id, hteam_id, vteam_id, loc, ....    I want the hteam_id and vteam_id to each be foreign key into the teams table.  How do you do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the two foreign key using this:

```
alter table game add foreign key game_hteam_id(hteam_id) references teams(id)
    , add foreign key game_vteam_id(vteam_id) references teams(id);
```

Comment: This is correct, but I'd recommend giving your foreign keys names, though.

Comment: Sorry Brian I do not understand your comment.

Comment: He recommends adding an explicit name to the foreign key contraints (else mysql will just give them default names like 'game_ibfk_1`); Just added this.

Answer (score 2):

First Read This:

[FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (id INT NOT NULL,
                     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE child (id INT, parent_id INT,
                    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
                    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id)
                      ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```